# Theorem on embedding of Mazes

Tags: general-topology, geometry, puzzle

I was reading the [Wikipedia article on mazes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze#Other_types_of_mazes) and at one point it makes with no citation the claim that 'Any maze can be mapped into a higher dimension without changing its topology.'

I assume they mean plane mazes, but what exactly is the geometric or topological theorem which they are referring to here?  Is it something like a generalisation of the Jordan curve theorem to higher dimension?

Comment: It would be nice if we can see that article too.

Comment: The statement is a little vague, but I'd assume they mean that you can map a maze into a higher dimension by extruding it, i.e., sending every point $p$ to $p \times (0,1)$ so as to build walls from the floor plan, so to speak.

Comment: Hmm is that really what they mean, that seems a bit trivial.  I guess that is probably the only possibility.

Comment: It's certainly trivial. Maybe they meant something else, but without elaboration, it's impossible to know. There are some comments, however, in the discussion of the article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Maze